# HTMLPurifier "referrerpolicy"

Tags: xss, htmlpurifier

I am trying to add ["refererpolicy"](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/#referrer-policy-delivery-referrer-attribute) and target="_blank" to the link tag using HTMLPurifier. I am able to achieve target="_blank" by

```
$config->set('HTML.TargetBlank', true);
```

which gives

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">Click</a>
```

However was not able to find a way to add "refererpolicy" from the docs.

Is there a way to add refererpolicy to the < a > tag using [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)?

Expected output

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" referrerpolicy="origin-when-cross-origin">
```